# MySQL Update Syntax Using Parentheses

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, syntax-error

In the following code $keyresult and $valueresult are comma separated lists of columns in my db and the values I want to put into them in the identified row. The problem is, the code isn't doing what I hoped it would and is returning a syntax error in the query.

```
$q3 = "UPDATE post SET ($keyresult) VALUES ('$valueresult') WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND post_id='$post_id' AND post_status='active'";
```

How can I fix the syntax of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing INSERT and UPDATE syntax.

```
$q3 = "UPDATE `post` SET `$keyresult` = '$valueresult' 
       WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND post_id='$post_id' AND post_status='active'";
```

I am assuming you are properly escaping `$valueresult`, `$user_id`, and `$post_id` *before* you are executing your query. If not, and these are user-supplied values, you are wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174). I recommend looking into [prepared statements](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) to eliminate this risk.

Comment: THe problem with this is that the $keyresult variable contains multiple columns (column 1, column 2, column 3) and the $valueresult has corresponding values (value 1, value 2, value 3). Running it like this gives a syntax error as well. And yes. They are escaped with mysqli_escape_string

Comment: Then you need to generate your query differently. The way you are approaching it won't work. A simple loop would make this simple.