# Update row in database with php and Microsoft sql

Tags: php, sql-server, database, sql-update

Hi im currently creating a blog, just to learn abit more about php, databases etc. Ive gotten so far that i want to be able to edit my posts. however i struggle to get it working...

this is what my code looks so far:

```
 <?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 $head =  $_POST['title'];
 $short = $_POST['short'];
$bread = $_POST['edit'];
$author = $_POST['author'];
$cat = $_POST['cat'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

 $db = new PDO('sqlsrv:server=localhost;Database=blog', '*****', '*********');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = 'UPDATE dbo.blog_posts SET (blog_title, blog_short, blog_post, blog_author, blog_category) VALUES (:head, :short, :bread, :author, :cat) WHERE blogID=$id';

$query = $db->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute( array(':head'=>$head, ':short'=>$short, ':bread'=>$bread, ':author'=>$author, ':cat'=>$cat ) );
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

now i get the error msg:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[07002]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]COUNT
>   field incorrect or syntax error' in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev\ny\post_edit.php:17 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev\ny\post_edit.php(17):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev\ny\post_edit.php on line 17

line 17 is the execute array

i have also tried:

```
 <?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 $head =  $_POST['title'];
 $short = $_POST['short'];
$bread = $_POST['edit'];
$author = $_POST['author'];
$cat = $_POST['cat'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

 $db = new PDO('sqlsrv:server=localhost;Database=blog', '*****', '*****');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = 'UPDATE dbo.blog_posts SET blog_title=(:head), blog_short=(:short), blog_post=(:bread), blog_author=(:author), blog_category=(:cat) WHERE blogID=:id';

$query = $db->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute( array(':head'=>$head, ':short'=>$short, ':bread'=>$bread, ':author'=>$author, ':cat'=>$cat ) );
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

that also gives the same error, cant really find how the execute line needs to be changed.

Edit:

When using this code below i only get a blank page again.. :/

```
 <?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 $head =  $_POST['title'];
 $short = $_POST['short'];
$bread = $_POST['edit'];
$author = $_POST['author'];
$cat = $_POST['cat'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

 $db = new PDO('sqlsrv:server=localhost;Database=blog', '******', '*****');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = UPDATE `blog_posts` SET `blog_title` = :head, `blog_short` = :short, `blog_post`  = :bread, `blog_author` = :author, `blog_category` = :cat WHERE `blogID` = :id;

$query = $db->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute( array(':id'=>$id, ':head'=>$head, ':short'=>$short, ':bread'=>$bread, ':author'=>$author, ':cat'=>$cat ) );

header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Comment: Add a semicolon after `$_POST['id']`

Comment: oh, now i get an error message atleast...

Comment: @LPK updated the post

Comment: Have a look at that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271964/mysql-update-syntax-using-parentheses - I think you mixup the SQL Update and Insert statements

Comment: @LPK Thanks, guess it should look like this = $sql = 'UPDATE dbo.blog_posts SET blog_title=$head blog_short=$short, blog_post=$bread, blog_author=$author, blog_category=$cat WHERE blogID=$id';      but how do i do the execute part of the script then?

Comment: Take a look at the official php PDOStatement docs. `:head`, `:short`... are only placeholders so I would try to replace `$` with `:` in your sql query.

Comment: Okey, ive tried everything i can... Cant seem to get this working properly... I Do have tried replacing $ with : but it does not change anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106789/discussion-between-lpk-and-per-kallstrom).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 $head =  $_POST['title'];
 $short = $_POST['short'];
$bread = $_POST['edit'];
$author = $_POST['author'];
$cat = $_POST['cat'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$postdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

 $db = new PDO('sqlsrv:server=localhost;Database=blog', '*****', '*****');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = 'UPDATE dbo.blog_posts SET blog_title= :head, blog_short= :short, blog_post= :bread, blog_author= :author, blog_category= :cat, blog_date= :postdate WHERE blogID= :id';


$query = $db->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute( array(':id'=>$id, ':head'=>$head, ':short'=>$short, ':bread'=>$bread, ':author'=>$author, ':postdate'=>$postdate, ':cat'=>$cat ) );

header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

This solved it for me! thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Change your query from:

```
UPDATE dbo.blog_posts 
SET (blog_title, blog_short, blog_post, blog_author, blog_category) 
VALUES (:head, :short, :bread, :author, :cat) 
WHERE blogID=$id
```

To:

```
UPDATE dbo.blog_posts
SET blog_title = :head,
    blog_short = :short, 
    blog_post  = :bread,
    blog_author = :author,
    blog_category` = :blog_category
WHERE blogID = :id
```

Then you also have to add `:id` to your execute array.

Comment: i tried but i get a blank page, i edited my post to show how i was using the code... thanks for taking your time to help me!

Comment: backticks are delimiters in mysql he`s using sql server (new PDO('sqlsrv:server..)

Comment: Ahhh okey I fixed it